# IIS8 - HTTP automatically forwards to HTTPS

Tags: windows, iis, http, https, iis-8

Currently I am running two sites (each one has an app Pool). One for HTTPS which is called `cloud` and the other one for HTTP content called `headsup`.

When I browse to the `domain.com/cloud` it all works fine through HTTPS automatically. But when I browse to `http://domain.com/headsup`, the browser automatically tries to reach `https://domain.com/headsup`.

I have limited knowledge about IIS and I can't seem to figure this out. The HTTP site is bound to port `*:80` and HTTPS is bound to port `*:443`. I have no forwards, rules or any other settings configured. Where should I look in order to separate HTTP and HTTPS back to how it used to be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cloud instance required SSL for the whole server so I disabled that. The problem was solved after a reboot of the machine.